# Extra external layer (shell) on my first prints

Tags: creality-ender-3, troubleshooting, underextrusion

I got my first 3D printer this week, a Creality Ender 3.

Tried to print a few small samples to test it, but every shape I printed had an extra external layer. Please, check these images:

[image: Photo of printed object with extra layer]

[image: Photo of extra layer, with layer pulled to one side]

I used Freecad to draw the objects, and Slic3r to convert them to G-code.

Am I doing something wrong? Is my printer not a good one?

Any comment will be very helpful.

Comment: It looks like under-extrusion. Have you changed something in printer settings? What settings did you change in Slic3r? Can you share one of G-code files that you are trying to print?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I didn't change anything. AFAIK I'm using factory settings. How can I share the G-code? I didn't find a way to upload files here.

Comment: You can't. But, you can upload it to some upload site and provide a link here.

Comment: See if you can access https://github.com/rppbodo/3d-printing/blob/main/cube-25mm.gcode

Comment: You should add this solution as a separate answer. It may help others in the future if someone also runs into this issue. Describe also, what exactly was causing it.

Comment: Dear Roberto, please post your update as an answer (the update is not part of the problem, it is a solution, I've hidden the part by placing it into an HTML comment block). SE differs from regular forum sites. It's perfectly fine to add your solution as an answer, you will receive votes and gain reputation. Please do the [tour] and look into [help] to better understand SE sites. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do some quick calculations it appears that this is caused by under-extrusion.

Comparing the extruded volume to the calculated volume for the deposition there is a mismatch of about 2.6. This hints to the use of an incorrect diameter for the filament $\frac{2.85^2}{1.75^2}=2.65$.

Comment: In line 4511 of provided G-code is: `; filament_diameter = 3`. It looks like you are right.

Comment: @kosteklvp I only looked at the first 20 lines or so, but good spot! 

Comment: Thank you so much for all the responses. I am waiting for more filament to arrive by mail. As soon as I manage to print again with correct filament diameter, I mark this problem as solved. I'll let you know.

Comment: I'm not sure, if you understood it correctly. You should change filament diameter value int the slicer to 1.75. Filaments with diameter of 3 mm are not very common.

Comment: 3 mm is not common, but 2.85 mm is pretty common, especially for UltiMaker printers. Nowadays is 1.75 mm mainstream for most users, only dinosaurs like me use it for their homebuilds. Note that you need to buy filament your printer is designed for, in this case 1.75 mm and use that value in your slicer.

Comment: Yes, I understood. hahaha The config was wrong, not the actual filament width. I bought more 1.75mm, because the sample that came with the printer ended. Thanks, everyone. =)

Comment: Yeah! I just printed with new G-code, and it is perfect! Thanks, everyone! <3

Comment: That's good, everything is clear.

Comment: Wow, why is this still a thing in 2023?!? 2.85/3 mm is pretty much a thing of the past, and should not be popping up in settings unless the user intentionally configured a weird printer.